# Windows phone Canvas element - active area for manipulation event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone

I have an ellipse within canvas in my windows phone application and I need to implement tap&drag behavior for it. I use ManipulationDelta event for that.

The problem is that ellipse is small and it is quite hard to touch it precisely and trigger manipulation. 
So the question is how can I increase the area around ellipse which is responsible handling user touch and triggering manipulation?

Comment: just put a transparent ellipse behind the main ellipse, and use MouseDragElementBehaviour instead, its easy to handle as compared to Manipulation events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take another bigger ellipse which is transparent and cannot be seen, keep the smaller ellipse on it, and then add the manipulation event on the bigger ellipse, what ever code you write, write it for the bigger one and your task is done.

Answer (score 1):

You've got multiple options, like Hatim's suggestion of a larger `Ellipse`. Or another shape like a `Rectangle` so the corner could get hit better etc. However you'll have to embed them both in a parent object anyway so they share the events and move together. So might as well just use the parent object. Could also just use `MouseDragElementBehavior` instead of messing with the `ManipulationDelta` if you wanted. Something like;

```
<Canvas>
  <Grid>
     <MouseDragElementBehavior/>
     <Ellipse/>
  </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Then you could use a `Margin` on the `Ellipse` or set the size of the parent `Grid` or a number of options to accommodate the requirements. Hope this helps.